# CrossRider - Is there a limit on the size of objects which are saved to the local database?

Tags: crossrider

We have an object which is downloaded from http://jsons.[part_of_link_suppressed].com.s3.amazonaws.com/selectors.json. We tried to save it to the local database, but nothing is saved. I checked and if I save a small object then it's saved to the database. Is there a limit on the size of objects which are saved to the local database? And if there is, what is the limit? Do we have to divide objects to small objects if we want to save them to the local database? And how do we divide arbitrary objects to small objects and save them to the database?

**Edit**: I refer to the synchronous database with the `appAPI.db` API.

Comment: We divided the object to several small objects, and now they are saved to the local database.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which crossrider db api your are using, but all of their storage apis have some size limitations. the file you linked to ain't big so i guess you are using the appAPI.db

The appAPI.db is very limited, as their current docs say:

> Use this method to save integers, booleans, short strings of
>   approximately 10 characters, and simple objects containing the
>   aforementioned types. If you need to save larger amounts of data, use
>   appAPI.db.async.
>   While the overall size limit of all entries is 5MB
>   http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db

With appAPI.db.async the limit is 1MB per key, 50MB total - that should do the work for you.
You can use their built it method to save remote resources to the async db: appAPI.db.async.setFromRemote

http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db.async

If you want to save even more space, you can serve your json string without linebreaks and spaces (minified/none pretty printed), or you can do it on the clientside before saving it to the db (JSON.parse then stringify it again).
Its very possible crossrider are doing it internally when you save js object and not string.

Comment: We prefer not to use `appAPI.db.async` because we want the data to be saved or loaded immediately, and not to use callbacks. If we use `appAPI.db`, what is the limit on the size of objects or strings? It can't be 10 characters because we saved bigger objects and strings. We will have to implement functions that will divide objects or strings to several smaller objects or strings.

Comment: In general, the exact size of an [appAPI.db](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db) key value varies between browser implemenations. For a consistent cross browser experience, it's recommend to use this database for storing small data and certainly limiting the size to no more 1000 bytes per key. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Whats the problem with callbacks? if you work with js you must know to work with async code.
And if the platform docs says its should be 10 chars and you save more because its currently works you are risking one day it will stop working without notice. and might behave differently across browsers.

Comment: @Shlomo your docs says "short strings of approximately 10 characters", not 1KB

Comment: The synchronous db is a bit like cookies; so even though it can store more, it's not recommended or encouraged. We originally did include the max size in the docs, but that changed when some browsers started limiting their local databases, hence rather than quote max size, we provide guidance for it's usage, i.e. it's ideal for storing small data such a config/state data.

Comment: @Bnaya it's easier for us to use the synchronous database without callbacks, unless the object we are saving is very big and in this case we will use the asynchronous database. I currently divided all objects to strings of 50 characters or less, this works with Internet Explorer 11 and that's what we need. But if there is a limit which is supported in all browsers, I would like to know what it is and we can change it accordingly. But 10 characters seems to me smaller than the actual limit.